# How to search own library in macOS' Music?

Tags: macos, music, search, apple-music, streaming

In macOS' *Music* app, I'd like to be able to search only within my local library (I have no interest in the streaming service):

[image]

However, there seems to be no options with the search bar, so it searches on Apple's streaming service instead of on my local device.

Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the Music app to search only your library rather than Apple Music or iTunes by using the search box on the top of the left sidebar of the app.

After clicking in that search box, click on one of the library names such as Apple Music, iTunes, or Your Library shown at the top right. (The exact library options would depend on which music related Apple services you are subscribed to.) Then write down your search term in the search box. Note that if one is subscribed Apple Music, "Your Library" would include any music added to "Your Library" in addition to those downloaded to the computer via the Music app.

You can check out this Apple support webpage for the macOS Music app called "[Search for music in Music on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/music/search-for-music-mus896f20db7/1.2/mac/12.0)" for more details.

Comment: I have no idea how I didn't spot this. Now I'm embarrassed. It'd be nice if we could customise it to search that way by default, but at least there's a simple solution! =)

Comment: It doesn't work for me on Monterey

Comment: @mmmmmm Sorry to hear that but I can confirm that the Music app search works well for going through content only in my library as described above with my MBP running on Monterey. Not sure how much I can eventually be of help but pls let me know through the comments here if you can't make it work at all and decide to ask about your Music search problem in a new post.

Comment: Ah I misread your answer - not helped by at top right I only have Apple Music and Your Library not what you suggest

Comment: Actualkly another problem is I usually have the history/net sidebar open so I do not have that choice

Comment: The "library names" selector does not show for me at all. There is just blank space there.